# Posts_per_page only shows 5 posts

Tags: wordpress

No matter what I put into the posts_per_page I just get 5 results.  I have looked everywhere and it seems posts_per_page => -1 should show all but also does nothing.  I need it to only show 15 posts.

Current code:

```html
<?php
//get category from URL
$productcatbyurl = str_replace('/','',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>

<ul>
<?php 
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array($productcatbyurl),
        'field' => 'slug',
        'posts_per_page'   => 15,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'terms' => array('general-operation'),
        'field' => 'slug',
        'posts_per_page'   => 15,
    ),
);

$myposts = get_posts( $myquery );
  foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; 
  wp_reset_postdata();?>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as now I have been looking at it so long that I am seeing nothing but a big blur.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us where `$myquery` is being initialised? `posts_per_page` is a field on the outermost array rather than within `tax_query`. [See here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Hello! Do you have any stick posts? If you do, maybe you can try to add: 
'ignore_sticky_posts'=>true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem: the `posts_per_page` parameter has to be on the same level as the `tax_query` key, not inside of it as you have it now. It should be like this:

```
$myquery['posts_per_page'] = 15;
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array($productcatbyurl),
        'field' => 'slug'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'terms' => array('general-operation'),
        'field' => 'slug'
    ),
);
```

Or written differently so it's more clear:

```
$myquery = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms' => array($productcatbyurl),
            'field' => 'slug'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms' => array('general-operation'),
            'field' => 'slug'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much.  Adding $myquery['posts_per_page'] = 15; before the query did it.  I will go back and clean it up now, thanks.